# reconnect to MQTT broker using Vertx library from Quarkus backend application

Tags: java, mqtt, quarkus, vert.x

I'm using Vertx to connect and subscribe to MQTT broker from a Quarkus backend application, the problem is when the broker is getting restarted or the connection gets lost, the client does not reconnect automatically again, is there a way a make an automatic reconnection?

Comment: Show us what you've tried and how you've configured the client.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.